# Ruby Key and value puts

Tags: ruby

Hi im new to programming Ruby and i need a little help.

I want to show the customers code and customer name when i do a check. But i only get the customer code and not the customer name. How do i get the customername too?

```
customer = {
C00001: "Tyler Dinges",
C00002: "Jannie de Vries",
C00003: "Klaas Bruinsma",
}

when 'searchcustomer'
puts "Witch customer are you looking for?"
customernumber = gets.chomp
if customer[customernumber.to_sym].nil?
  puts "customer is not found"
else
  customernumber == customer[customernumber.to_sym]
  customer[customernumber.to_sym]
  puts "#{customernumber} #{customername} Is a customer!"
end
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to do `customername = customer[customernumber.to_sym]` so that the `customername` variable holds the name.

Comment: Normally `when` is used with `case`. Where is your `case`?

Comment: This is a little part of my code.

Comment: @shirakia Please don't remove code from a question if it is not fully clear it was a non-related error by the poster. Here, it was part of the overall issue and editing the code deviated from the original intend and made the question more confusing.

Comment: It's worth noting that `if x.nil? ... else` is almost always better served with `if x ... else` and reversing the blocks unless there's ever a case where `x` could be literal `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `when` keyword.

```
customer = {
    C00001: "Tyler Dinges",
    C00002: "Jannie de Vries",
    C00003: "Klaas Bruinsma",
}


puts "Witch customer are you looking for?"
customernumber = gets.chomp
if customer[customernumber.to_sym].nil?
  puts "customer is not found"
else
  customername = customer[customernumber.to_sym]
  puts "#{customernumber} #{customername} Is a customer!"
end
```

I removed `customernumber == customer[customernumber.to_sym]` because its already assigned by `gets`

Comment: Thanks it works!!!

I need the when cause i have a case. But forgot too put it the example. but this works man thanks!!